# How can I disable the submit button until text is entered in the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue try to achieve this result, pretty much what I need is to disable the submit button until text is entered in the input field. I've trying some functions but without results.

HTML Markup

```
<form action="" method="get" id="recipename">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="recipe-name" 
    value="Have a good name for it? Enter Here" 
    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Have a good name for it? Enter Here') {this.value = '';}" 
    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Have a good name for it? Enter Here';}" 
/>
<input type="submit" class="submit-name" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var initVal = "Have a good name for it? Enter Here";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");
    $(".recipe-name").blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != initVal && $(this).val() != "") {
            $(".submit-name").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");        
        }
    });    
});
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3RZV/).

Answer (score 7):

The only problem with the accpeted solution is that the button is enabled only after focus is removed from the text field (after entering data in it of course). Shouldnt the button be enabled as soon as any text is entered in the field? Here is a solution that implements this.

Link to other solution: [Keep button disabled if text is not entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957208/keep-button-disabled-if-text-is-not-entered)

something like this:

```
$('.recipe-name').on("keyup", action);
function action() {
   if($('.recipe-name').val().length > 0) {
      $('#submit-name').prop("disabled", false);
   }else {
      $('#submit-name').prop("disabled", true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

call some javascript function like below(giving example for jquery) in onkeyup event

```
function handleSubmit()
{
if($.trim($('#name').val() == ''))
{
$('.submit-name').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else
{
$('.submit-name').attr('disabled','');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textField").keyup(function() {
    var $submit = $(this).next(); // or $("#submitButton");
    if(this.value.length > 0 && this.value != "Default value") {
        $submit.attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $submit.attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var nameText = $("#name");

nameText.attr("disabled", "disabled");

nameText.change(function () {
  if(nameText.val().length > 0) {
    nameText.attr("disabled", "");
  } else {
    nameText.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }

});
```

Comment: don't forget to trim value before checking for length

Answer (score 0):

```
    const controls = document.querySelectorAll("input, select");
    for (const c of controls){
      c.oldValue = c.value + c.checked;
    }
    var trackControls;
    (trackControls = function() {
      var disabled = true;
      for (const c of controls) {
        if (c.oldValue !== (c.value + c.checked)) {
          disabled = false;
          break;
        }
      }
        var selector = document.querySelector("[type=submit]");
        if (selector != null) { 
              selector.disabled = disabled; 
        }
    })();
    document.oninput = trackControls;
    document.onchange = trackControls;
```

If you're not concerned about the cross browser compatibility. const does not work in IE