# Keep button disabled if text is not entered

Tags: jquery

I want to achieve something like this.
I have 4 text fields and one select field that are required for the form to submit. I want to keep the button disabled unless the text field has values and an option is selected from the dropdown. My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2mRd/3/)

The problem I have is whenever I enter the data in the 4 text fields and though the dropdown is selected to the default text the button gets enabled. After I change the dropdown it is disabled forever.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C2mRd/6/)

```
$('#fname, #lname, #zipcode').on("keyup", action);
$('#location').on("change", action);

function action() {
    if( $('#fname').val().length > 0 && $('#lname').val().length > 0 && $('#zipcode').val().length > 0 && $('#location').val() != '' ) {
        $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Zoltan: There is a bug in the code I guess, when all the text fields are entered first and then the drop down is selected the button is disabled

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery:

```
var text_valid = false, dropdown_valid = false;
$("input[type='text'].required:focus").each(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
        text_valid = true
    }
}

if($("#mydropdown option:selected").length){
    dropdown_valid = true;
}

if(text_valid && dropdown_valid) {// Our form is valid
    $("#mybutton").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else { // Our form is invalid
    $("#mybutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could count how many inputs have text

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var count = $('input:text').filter(function(){return $(this).val() == "";}).size();
});
```

But, since you are using a select tag I think you should check as well whether it has a value.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var count = $('input:text').filter(function(){return $(this).val() == "";}).size()
            + $('select:text').filter(function(){return $(this).val() == "";}).size();
    if(count > 0){
        $('#submit').button({disabled: true});
    }else{
        $('#submit').button({disabled: false});
    }
});
```